# Laravel Livewire Validation With Database Column

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-livewire

I have a projects table contains contract column. contract column is nullable. Because some projects may not have contract. If a project have contract, contract must be accepted:

```
// Blade 
@if($project->contract)
<div>
    <div class="inline-flex items-center space-x-2">
        <input wire:model.defer="contract" id="contract" type="checkbox">
        <label for="contract">I accept <a href="#">contract</a></label>
        @error('contract')
            <span class="text-xs text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>
@endif


// Component
$this->validate([
        'contract' => 'accepted',
    ],

// Tried like this too
$this->validate([
        'contract' => 'exists:projects|accepted',
    ],
```

I tried theese but null contract tables are validating too. How can I validate this null columns?

Answer (score 1):

write this

```
if(isset(request('contract'))){
     $this->validate([
                'contract' => 'exists:projects|accepted',
            ]
  }
```

Comment: Tried but giving me another validation error: "The selected contract is invalid."

Comment: can you share the controller's code?

Comment: if(isset(request('contract'))){
$this->validate([
            'contract' => 'exists:projects|accepted',
        ],
}

Comment: I've used like this (accepted_if rule) and looks like working:

public function render()
    {
  if($this->project->contract){
   $this->contractValue = 1;
  }else{
   $this->contractValue = 0;
  }
        return view('livewire.single-project')->extends('layouts.app')->section('content');
    }

$this->validate([
'contract' => 'accepted_if:contractValue,1',
]);